# After publishing a new version of a game to App Store old versions stopped receiving ads from admob

Tags: ios, admob, app-store

I use admob for interstitial and rewarded ads.

Apple accepted the updated version of my game 1.5 days ago. Now I see on the admob dashboard in "Today so far" section that despite having 3.56K Requests I only have 5 Impressions (I'm quite sure from the new version) and 1.12% Match Rate, look at the screenshot below:
[image: admob dashboard]

In App Store I have slightly changed the app name, but that's all. On the admob side I did not change anything.

Older versions (on devices already installed on) stopped receiving both interstitial and rewarded ads, but on the new version it works well.

I have updated my app multiple times (without the slight name change) but nothing similar has happened.

What can cause this? I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found is: it might happen without any real cause, Google might test developer/app for some purpose.

The problem usually goes away in a couple of days / few weeks, but not in every case.

Not sure about the why.